# null pointer exception in reading tsv file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

hi can anybody help me with below code. why this is throwing null pointer exception and how i can avoid it.
i am trying to read a tsv file and csv file and do some processing with this.
when i am calling getDictionaryValues function it throwing null pointer exception.

```
package com.ugam.qa.tittle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class TittleMatch {
private static TittleMatchUtil tMU;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fullname="d:/files/listing/Headphones.tsv";
    Set<String> attributeSet=new HashSet<String>();
    attributeSet.add("Storage Type");
    attributeSet.add("Recording Definition");
    attributeSet.add("Type");
    attributeSet.add("Brand");
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("file found");
        in= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullname));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();


    }
    String str;
    String prv_Pid="-1";
    try {
        str =  in.readLine();
        while ((str =  in.readLine()) != null) {

            if (str.trim().length() == 0 ) {
                System.out.println("while loop");
                continue;}

            String[] values = str.split("\\t");
            //System.out.println(values.length);
            if(prv_Pid=="-1" || values[9]==prv_Pid)
            {
                if(attributeSet.contains(values[12]))
                {
                    ArrayList<Set<String>> dicValues=new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
                    if(values[12]!=null && values[13]!=null)
                    {
                        dicValues=tMU.getDictionaryValues(values[12],values[13]);
                    }
                    //Set<String> tittle=new HashSet<String>();
                    //tittle.add(values[8]);
                    //System.out.println(tittle);

                }
            }

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Paste the stacktrace, please.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ugam.qa.tittle.TittleMatch.main(TittleMatch.java:50)

Comment: OT: Use `String.equals` to compare strings `if (prv_Pid.equals("-1")`

Comment: @user2696466 and which line is that? Please edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this variable is evaluated to `null`, since you never assign a value to it.

```
private static TittleMatchUtil tMU;
```

One solution would be assigning a new `TittleMatchUtil` object to the variable:

```
private static TittleMatchUtil tMU = new TittleMatchUtil();
```

and another one is to make the `getDictionaryValues()` method `static`, which I wouldn't do, because it may require more code re-factoring.

Comment: if i dont put static it is showing error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field tMU". plz suggest how to correct this.

Comment: `private static TittleMatchUtil tMU = new TittleMatchUtil();`